# Need a searchable drop down list in yii

Tags: jquery, database, list, drop-down-menu, yii

I want to make a searchable drop down list in yii, which takes data from the database just like in this link [demo](http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/site/widget?view=autocomplete) and store it in the database. I know how to make a drop down list, but my task is to create a searchable drop down list, like when i start typing, the drop down list opens and shows data from the database. 
I am in (package) view, in which (package-item) is the the field on which want the searchable drop down.

```
<?php
/* @var $this PackageController */
/* @var $model Package */
/* @var $form BSActiveForm */
?>
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'package-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'package_name',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>

    <?php  echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'package_item',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>


    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'package_detail',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>

    <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: try yii's select2 extension.

Answer (score 0):

- If you just want the **`autocomplete`** then this could help:

In your view:

```
<?php
echo "<div class='auto-search'>";
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
      'id'=>'package_item',
      'name'=>'package_item',
      'source'=>$this->createUrl('site/suggestItem'),
      'htmlOptions'=>array(
          'class'=>'package_item',
          'placeholder'=>"Search package.."
      ),
    ));
echo "</div>";
?>
```

In your controller (in this case `siteController`) create a new action:

```
<?php
public function actionsuggestItem()
    {
        $request    = trim($_GET['term']);
        $data       = array();
        if($request != ''){
            //your query to database to get package items.
            $packageModel = Package::model()->findAll("packagename=$request");
            foreach($packageModel as $get){
                $data[] = $get->packagename;
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
?>
```

- If you want both **`dropdown`** and **`autocomplete`**

then you could use this [Select2 Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/)

In your view:

```
<?php $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'attribute'=>'package_item',
      'data'=>$model->searchItem(),
    ); ?>
```

In your model:

```
<?php
    public function searchItem() {
        $data         = array();
        $packageModel = Package::model()->findAll();
        foreach($packageModel as $get){
            $data[] = $get->packagename;
        }
        return $data;
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
?>
```

Note that these are just examples, modify them according to your need.

Comment: if i want to use select 2 extension, i want the data from the database, not like this
'data'=>array(
        0=>'Nol',
        1=>'Satu',
        2=>'Dua',

Comment: @UsmanDabayKhan Create a function in your model and call it in the `data` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
  'name'=>'package_item',
  'data'=>CHtml::listData(Package::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'package_item'), //the whole available list
  'htmlOptions'=>array(
       'placeholder'=>' search packge item?',
    //'options'=>$options, //the selected values
    'multiple'=>'multiple',
    'style'=>'width:530px',
  ),
  ));
```

did this and now its working. Thanks god.Drop down was created, but it was not searchable, then i comment out the jquery, and now its working.But my next question is how can i store multiple values in database?